# How to use jest to test React class component fetch().then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

The js code probably looks like this

```
import CModel from "xxxx";
const cModel = new CModel();

cModel.fetch(xxxxxx，{
        body: {type: 1}
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.errCode == 0) {
           // ...
         }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      });
```

I tried using jest.mock and spyOn, but I had no clue.I searched a lot of information, but I don’t seem to have encountered a similar situation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do `spyOn` + `mockImplementation`.

Example

```
import CModel from "xxxx";

const cModelSpy = jest
  .spyOn(CModel, 'fetch')
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('some payload here'))
```

Replace anything with `'some payload here'` with the test data you would like to reach to the `.then` block.

Likewise, you can also replace `Promise.resolve` part with `Promise.reject` to test the `catch` block of your code.

You can also make it slightly more reusable by doing

```
const cModelSpy = jest.spyOn(CModel, 'fetch')

beforeEach(() => {
  cModelSpy.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('some payload here')) // default mock
})
afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks()
})
```

then in each test, you can do the mock implementation with `cModelSpy.mockImplementation(...)`

cheers